# .htacces to web.config convertor

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis, web-config, url-rewriting

I am wondering if there is a .htaccess to web.config convertor on the web that I could use?

I am trying to convert this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?file=$1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For IIS7 and above, information on this page might be helpful.
There is a built in converting wizard.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules